# Creating a SOAP request with XML with Grails

Tags: xml, grails, soap

I need to construct a method that sends XML with a certain pattern. But I do not find a way to build this with Grails. Here's the XML example I need to build. Can anyone help me?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sic="http://www.example.com/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <sic:IncPrePrTyped>
   <sic:clsProp>
    <sic:datDataSist>2017-02-02</sic:datDataSis>
    <sic:datDataVali>2017-02-02</sic:datDataVali>
    <sic:strEmpr>01</sic:strEmp>
    <sic:strProd>0071</sic:strProd>
    <sic:strBand02</sic:strBand>
    <sic:strFil>0001</sic:strFil>
    <sic:strPontAtend>3424</sic:strPontAtend>
    <sic:strAtend>A5F1</sic:strAtend>
    <sic:datDataProp>2017-02-01</sic:datDataProp>
    <sic:strClient>24517666034</sic:strClient>
    <sic:strName>BENTO DA SILVA AMARAL</sic:strName>
    <sic:strDataNasc>27/06/1952</sic:strDataNasc>
   </sic:clsProp>
  </sic:IncPrePropTyped>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I don't believe that you did not find any info like http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/10/groovy-goodness-creating-xml-with.html on that so far...

Comment: I had already seen this link. I got to test but could not reproduce a similar output. If you have a larger domain, show me a similar example of the output example I need. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
writer = xmlBuilder.bind {
    mkp.declareNamespace( 'soapenv': "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" )
    mkp.declareNamespace( 'sic': "http://www.example.com/" )
    'soapenv:Envelope' {
        'soapenv:Header'()
        'soapenv:Body' {
            'sic:IncPrePrTyped' {
                'sic:clsProp' {
                    'sic:datDataSist'('2017-02-02')
                    'sic:datDataVali'('2017-02-02')
                    'sic:strEmpr'('01')
                    'sic:strProd'('0071')
                    'sic:strBand'('02')
                    'sic:strFil'('0001')
                    'sic:strPontAtend'('3424')
                    'sic:strAtend'('A5F1')
                    'sic:datDataProp'('2017-02-01')
                    'sic:strClient'('24517666034')
                    'sic:strName'('BENTO DA SILVA AMARAL')
                    'sic:strDataNasc'('27/06/1952')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( writer )
```